# Is it safe to concatenate a double quoted to a single quoted string?

Tags: php, html, quotes

Are there any issues I should be aware of when doing the following:

```
$table_html = '  <td id="unescaped-double-quotes-yay">Some stuff</td>' . "\n";
```

I do not like escaping double quotes withing HTML and I can't stand using single quotes in HTML, my solution is what I have above.  Am I going to run into any issues with this practice?

Comment: A string value is a string value: it makes no difference from which expression (including string literal expressions) it comes from. I personally think that looks extra ugly .. and would recommend a proper template library or (more DIY) [heredocs / nowdocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Yes, very astute of you; however, my question wasn't "what is a string value?".

Comment: If it's plain text like what you have in your example then no.

Comment: As for the ugliness, I disagree, to a point. It really depends on the application.

Comment: @ElefantPhace I do include *"I"* to bring along the personal nature. Preferences aside, the behavior is well-defined.

Comment: @user2864740 - I replied to your original comment "A string value is a string value".  And then you edited to elaborate, you sneaky devil.

Comment: @JamesHuckabone I do edit alot :}

Comment: @user2864740 - hehe, but getting back to it, you totally didn't answer my question.  All I was asking was is it ok to do: $string = 'asdfasdf' . "\n";

Comment: @JamesHuckabone That has nothing to do about "safety" of the concatenation operation, but about coding style. *I* personally think it looks like poo, but I'd also say the same for any mass of string concatenation. Templates, now/heredocs, and formatted (interpolated/sprintf) strings can make the code, arguably influenced by preference, much easier to grok then trying to mentally line up which-quote-is-for-which - not to mention which HTML end tag belongs to which start tag.

Comment: @user2864740 -- To be honest, I don't care about your preferred coding style.  My question was exactly about any unforeen safety issue mixing/concatenating single and double quotes.  And since you have no idea of the context, you really shouldn't be foisting your unusable ideas on to me.  How am I going to use heredoc in a foreach loop that has for loops for certain table cells?  Anyways I got my answer from Naterade, a reasonable, knowledgable human being...

Comment: @JamesHuckabone From a technical point it is "well defined" and "safe". From a "preference" point, it is absolute trash. And here I was trying to be kind. (Note that such "preferences" often come from many thousands of hours of practical experience.) Code that is hard to read is hard to maintain. Code that does not force strict separation of boundaries makes it easy to miss 'simple' things - like proper output escaping, which allow an XSS attack. So while the code presented is  entirely "safe" it is part of a fundamentally weak infrastructure without good "in my opinion" coding standards.

Comment: @JamesHuckabone As this question is worded, however, the answer is entirely contained in the first sentence of my first comment.

Comment: @JamesHuckabone That was me being *factual* and using a simple tautology to explain what is going on. And here I was trying to be nice [about the code presented]. And no, I'm not getting worked up, because this means very little to me - hence why my comment about being nice has *nothing* to do with you personally, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this many times on client sites (have since found better alternatives), you are 100% fine.

Comment: Thank you for the reinforcement.

Comment: No problem, ignore the down vote B.S. People need help and reassurance, we've all been there.

Comment: I really don't care about the downvotes.  Although I do fantasize about eating their souls.

Answer (score 1):

You MUST escape strings that comes from DB or from the user because they could easily break you concatenation if the unexpected kind of quote is present in that string (not to mention that you MUST cleanse anything that comes from the user for minimal security). 
Other than that you can concatenate strings any way you like. Still, life will always be easier if you manage to use them cosistently the same way.

Comment: Sorry about the confusing comment, I really appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the following representation:

```
$table_html = <<<HTML
 <td id="unescaped-double-quotes-yay">
   Some stuff, and i can use normal newlines here
  </td>
HTML;
```

It is called "heredoc", and you must keep in mind that the final string must be equivalent to the opening one, and must be the **only** thing on the line (no spaces or even comments are allowed).

You must also terminate the last line with the newline, even if it is the last line in the file.

To read more about it click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)